# Set QNetworkRequest to always PreferCache

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I have a QWebView, I have created a QNetworkDiskCache and set it. Now I would like to ensure that all QNetworkRequests always use PreferCache instead of PreferNetwork.

How do I go about setting this? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way via

```
webView->page()->networkAccessManager()
```

I wonder of course, if I even need to do this, what I want to accomplish is: I have a custom browser, it connects to a special intranet site, I would like it to cache almost permanently all images, css, and js sent by the server unless told otherwise.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You could derive the class `QNetworkAccessManager` and redefine its virtual function `createRequest` like this:

```
QNetworkReply * MyNetworkManager::createRequest(
    QNetworkAccessManager::Operation operation, 
    const QNetworkRequest & originalRequest, 
    QIODevice * device) 
{
    QNetworkRequest request = originalRequest;
    if(request.attribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute) == 
       QNetworkRequest::PreferNetwork)
    {
        request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, 
            QNetworkRequest::PreferCache);
    }
    return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(operation, request, device);
}
```